# Ubuntu root can't give any permissions?

Tags: permissions, root

Information about my Ubuntu:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I have a problem. I can't give any permissions nor change them as a root (sudo su, sudo -i etc). What should I do? How do I find the cause of this? How to fix it?

```
sudo nano test.sh
```

Output: `Error writing lock file ./.test.sh.swp: Permission denied`

Giving an user account its own permissions:

```
sudo chown -R student121:student121 /home/opilane121/
```

Output: Tons of Operation not permitted texts

**Answer to comments:**

1) NFS4 is **read-write only**

2) Output of **`mount | grep home`:**

```
mount | grep home
10.16.122.2:/data/users/students on /home type nfs4  (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,po    rt=0,timeo=14,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.16.122.146,local_lock=none,addr= 10.16.122.2)
```

Comment: I don't know your issue, but are you trying to change details on a read-only device/partition?  Is it mounted read-write? or read-only?  (has the file-system got errors that need fixing before you can mount it read-write?)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the output of `mount | grep /home`

Comment: Hi there! I updated the post. Answered to your questions and included the output of that command. Please, take a look at it, sir/ma'am.

Comment: The fact that you mount the NFS as r/w doesn't mean that the server gives you full rights on it (especially NFS4...)

Comment: Hmm. What should I do then? Where should I start doing things? :( I'm clueless right now. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFS-server is probably running with `root_squash`:

> Very often, it is not desirable that the root user on a client machine is also treated as root when accessing files on the NFS server. To this end, uid 0 is normally mapped to a different id: the so-called anonymous or nobody uid. This mode of operation (called 'root squashing') is the default, and can be turned off with no_root_squash.

It basically maps root to a different user with least privileges. This is the default setting on NFS.

Talk with you server administrator, or if you are the server administrator, add option `no_root_squash` to the `/etc/exports` on the server.